# How to make CTRL+D exit zsh with partial command line

Tags: zsh

In *zsh*, `CTRL-D` doesn't work unless the current line is empty. So to exit if I have written something I have to either press `CTRL+C` or `CTRL+U` and then `CTRL+D`.

How to make `CTRL+D` work even if the command line is not empty?

(I'm using arch linux with mate-terminal)

Comment: This behaviour is IMHO not specific to _zsh_, I observe it also for _bash_, _ksh_, _tcsh_.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a shell function which exits the shell and bind it to `^D` which represents `CTRL+D`:

```
exit_zsh() { exit }
zle -N exit_zsh
bindkey '^D' exit_zsh
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually the only solution that worked for me just with pure zsh!

Comment: This only partially works on modern Macs: it does end the session, but it doesn't close the terminal; you're left with `Saving session... ...copying shared history... ...saving history...truncating history files... ...completed. [Process completed]`

Comment: @machineghostm: This sounds like some special behaviour of the terminal emulator and/or some zsh "plugins" like oh-my-zsh for example?! Can you try with `exec zsh -f` and some other terminal emulator?